# flask request args parser error The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

using test_client and sending a request like so:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
client = app.test_client()

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': u'Bearer fake_token_123'}
params = {'dont_care': True}
client.get(ֿֿ'/my_route/123', query_string=params, headers=headers)
```

my route is

```
class MyController(Resource):

    def get(self, id):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument('currency', type=str, default='USD', help="help text")

        args = parser.parse_args()
        currency_from_params = args.currency
```

`parser.parse_args()` failing for

```
The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand
```

when removing `'content-type': 'application/json'` from header **it works**.

I don't understand this behaviour, and how do I protect against it without the un elegant `try, expect`.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already discovered how to fix it: don't send `content-type: application/json` if you're not posting JSON. You can't send JSON with GET, and even if you could (or were using POST) you would have to encode the JSON with `json.dumps(data)` first.

Answer (score 0):

This error also appears if you put your key value pairs in a POST into the request parameters instead of creating a proper JSON.